# Unity 5.x: Where's the RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to do something like

```
Container.RegisterType<ISettingsService, SettingsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Before v5 I was using `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;` for this.
Does the generic method still exists in v5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the namespace `Unity` in the `Unity.Abstractions` package, so

```
using Unity;
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thanks!. I don't understand why VS 2017 is not able to suggest `using Unity`. It usually does. Just curious why it doesn't for this. I rebuilt but it still can't suggest it.

Comment: Resharper does, too

Comment: You mean Resharper is able to suggest it?

Comment: It did for me (2017.2.2 I think)